# How to properly prevent TextInput blur on react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

In order to make a custom input, I had to create an `InputWrapper` to apply common style and add some animation behavior:

```js
import React, { ReactElement, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet, View, TouchableWithoutFeedbackProps,
} from 'react-native';
import Text from './Text';
import { Colors, Theme } from '../constants';
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

interface Props extends TouchableWithoutFeedbackProps {
  label: string;
  value?: any;
  children: any;
  focus: boolean;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // ...
});

const InputWrapper = ({
  label, value, children, focus, ...props
}: Props): ReactElement => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setShow(focus || Boolean(value));
  }, [focus, value])

  return (
    <View
      style={[
        styles.container,
        focus ? styles.containerFocus : {},
      ]}
    >
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback {...props}>
        <View style={[
          styles.wrapper,
          focus ? styles.wrapperFocus : {},
        ]}>
          <Text
            style={[
              styles.label,
              show ? styles.labelActive : {},
            ]}
          >
            {label}
          </Text>
          {show && children}
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
  );
};

export default InputWrapper;
```

I implemented the wrapper with the `TextInput` native component:

```js
import React, { ReactElement, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  TextInputProps, TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
import InputWrapper from './InputWrapper';
import InputValue, { InputValueStyles } from './InputValue';

interface Props extends TextInputProps {
  label?: string;
}

const Input = ({
  label, value, ...props
}: Props): ReactElement => {
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);
  const input = useRef(null);

  const onWrapperPress = (): void => {
    setFocus(true);
  }

  const onInputFocus = (): void => {
    setFocus(true);
  }

  const onInputBlur = (): void => {
    setFocus(false);
  }

  return (
    <InputWrapper
      label={label}
      value={value}
      focus={focus}
      onPress={onWrapperPress}
    >
      {!focus && <InputValue value={value} />}
      {focus && <TextInput
        autoFocus={focus}
        style={InputValueStyles.input}
        value={value}
        onFocus={onInputFocus}
        onBlur={onInputBlur}
        ref={input}
        {...props}
      />}
    </InputWrapper>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

All works perfectly except one thing: If you press on the touchable overlay of the focuses input, you will lose this focus because it triggered the `blur` input event.

The question is quite simple then: How to prevent this?

I also tried other ways with the disabled prop of the touchable area or blur event preventing without any luck.

If you also have a better way to handle my need, I'm not against propositions. :-)